# List Index out of range, trying to get the [-1] position

Tags: python-3.x, list

I've tested to see if the list is empty and I'm sure it's not empty. So why this error continues?
The code is to find the smallest amount of factorial to a sum is equal to `N`.

```
def fat(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1 
    else:
        return n * fat(n - 1) 

n = int(input())
ns = [x+1 for x in range(n)]
listaFat = []
l = []
for x in ns:
    if fat(x) < n:
       listaFat.append(x)
maior = max(listaFat)
listaFat.remove(maior)

print(listaFat)
print(len(listaFat))
while (fat(listaFat[-1]) + fat(maior)) < n:
   l.append(listaFat[-1])
   if len(listaFat) > 0:
       listaFat.remove(listaFat[-1])
       continue
   else: break


print(l)
print(listaFat)
```

Comment: Because you keep removing items from `listaFat` and at some point it's empty, so `listaFat[-1]` doesn't find anything.

Comment: In future, please include which line you're getting the error at. It's at the while loop check in this case.

Comment: You check whether the list is empty... and then *after* checking, you immediately empty it.